# Is it legal to have children of an anchor tag (<a>) in HTML?

Tags: html, anchor, parent-child

Is it legal to have children of an anchor tag in HTML? For an example:

```
 <a>
     <font>Example</font>
     <img src="example.jpg"/>
 </a>
```

It works fine in the browsers.But is it valid? Please help

Comment: Yes it is legal. The HTML police won't try arresting you.

Comment: It used to be that some elements were legal, some were not.  For example, you could not place block elements within the a tag (div, ul, p, etc).  Inline elements were acceptable (span, font, img, em, strong, etc).  But apparently html5 changed all that!

Comment: <font> very old school, btw.

Comment: @cale_b: Yes, HTML5 does change it (to be inline with what browsers actually did anyway), *depending* on the context in which the `a` tag is used. `a` has become "transparent," which basically means it adopts whatever its container's content model is. So the above is valid **provided** it's valid to have a `<font>` and `<img>` in that location. (Of course, it's *never* valid to have a `<font>` tag anywhere, as of HTML5.)

Comment: The question now is, is it good practice?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes - even more so with the advent of [HTML 5 (From the spec)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a):

> Although previous versions of HTML restricted the a element to only containing phrasing content (essentially, what was in previous versions referred to as “inline” content), the a element is now transparent; that is, an instance of the a element is now allowed to also contain [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#flow-content) (essentially, what was in previous versions referred to as “block” content)—if the parent element of that instance of the a element is an element that is allowed to contain flow content.

Comment: Thnks Adrift. I want to know how css positioning of a child element can affect the parent anchor tag?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all versions of HTML allow some elements inside an `a` element. The set of allowed elements depends on the HTML version. The code posted is valid HTML 3.2 and HTML 4.01 as far as element nesting goes, though the `img` element is not valid HTML 4.01 due to lack of `alt` attribute.