# Allowed children for an <a> element?

Tags: css, html

I have been working with a lot of `html` structuring lately and I started to wonder what are the elements that are allowed as children of an `<a>` element?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289583/is-it-legal-to-have-children-of-an-anchor-tag-a-in-html

Comment: You can always test what's valid and what's not http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Changes in HTML5
>
> Although previous versions of HTML restricted the a element to only containing phrasing content (essentially, what was in previous versions referred to as “inline” content), the a element is now transparent; that is, an instance of the a element is now allowed to also contain flow content (essentially, what was in previous versions referred to as “block” content)—if the parent element of that instance of the a element is an element that is allowed to contain flow content.

[HTML language reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a)

Comment: But it can't contain such elements as <button>, another <a>, etc

Comment: please don't copy answers form other posts (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18289616/1811992)

Answer (score 5):

Anything as long as there insn't any interactive content like buttons, forms, other link...

w3.org HTML5 specs :

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links).

see [link to source](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

And here is an example of what you can do (still form w3.org) :

```
<aside class="advertising">
    <h1>Advertising</h1>
    <a href="http://ad.example.com/?adid=1929&amp;pubid=1422">
        <section>
            <h1>Mellblomatic 9000!</h1>
            <p>Turn all your widgets into mellbloms!</p>
            <p>Only $9.99 plus shipping and handling.</p>
        </section>
    </a>
    <a href="http://ad.example.com/?adid=375&amp;pubid=1422">
        <section>
            <h1>The Mellblom Browser</h1>
            <p>Web browsing at the speed of light.</p>
            <p>No other browser goes faster!</p>
        </section>
    </a>
</aside>
```