# Is it correct to put a 'p' inside an 'a'?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I just watched this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOloTS7HTTU) about Bootstrap, and I saw a `p` inside an `a`. I would like to know if it is correct semantically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it legal to have children of an anchor tag (<a>) in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289583/is-it-legal-to-have-children-of-an-anchor-tag-a-in-html)

Comment: I saw the similar question. It works for me. Tks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is allowed (since HTML5, where the [`a` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) has a [transparent](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#transparent) content model) if

- the `a` element is valid at this position, and
- the `p` element would be valid at `a`’s position, too.

([More detailed answer about the transparent content model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39043351/1591669))