# Wrapping DIV inside Anchor tag or otherwise

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have a clickable complex `div` element structure which links to another page as follows. This is the thing that is being achieved currently on click.
On click (css :active state) change the background color inside `<a>` tag and redirect to other page.

I am wondering whether this conforms to HTML5 validation or consider as a best practice compared to wrapping it with a `div` and using JavaScript to manage the link redirect and background color change on click.

To me, the first approach seems to be much cleaner and straight forward.

I believe this is a common issue face by a lot of web developers but I am not sure whether there is an existing best practice solution for this.

1) Maintain as this

```
<a href="page1.html">
    <div>
        <!-- complex layout -->
    </div>
</a>
```

2) Omit the `<a>` tag and manage background color during click event and redirect using JavaScript

```
<div id="#redirectLink" data-link="page1.html">
    <!-- complex layout -->
</div>
```

Comment: you can do `window.location="some_Website_link"`on `onClick`

Comment: Aside from pure HTML5 validity, I'd go for CSS-only over Javascript any day, both for performance and compatibility reasons (in case someone has Javascript disabled or uses a system which doesn't support it). Javascript should handle functionality, while CSS should handle visual design. Your source code will be much more readable, which will mostly benefit your. Also, crawlers will be able to analyze your page for hyperlinks.

Comment: `(•_•)` @TheThirdMan quoting your comment *`"I'd go for CSS-only over Javascript any day"`* ... what? *`"Also, crawlers will be able to analyze your page for hyperlinks"`* huh? Can you please show an example where one, **using CSS-only** can convert an element to a link?

Comment: @Roko: It was poorly phrased on my end - what I meant was using pure CSS to change an element's appearance rather than have javascript do it, based on a basic HTML construct using the a tag. Both CSS and JS assume a respectively constructed markup for them to work, so I was omitting that in my previous description.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**HTML5**, you **can** wrap a `DIV` inside an `A` [anchor](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a)

```
<a href="page1.html">
    <div>
        <!-- complex layout - WITHOUT ANCHORS OR BUTTONS -->
    </div>
</a>
```

**only if** inside `<!-- complex layout -->` you don't have another `<a>` or Form-action elements like `<button>` etc.

Otherwise you can do:

```
<div id="#redirectLink" data-link="page1.html">
    <!-- complex layout -->
</div>

<script>
document.querySelectorAll("[data-link]").forEach( el =>  {
   el.addEventListener("click", () => window.location.href = el.dataset.link);
});
</script>
```

or simply:

```
<div id="#redirectLink" onclick="window.location.href='page1.html';">
    <!-- complex layout -->
</div>
```

but inline JavaScript is bad design since hard to maintain and debug, so prefer having it in your script files.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach conforms to HTML5. a-tags can have children, just not more links.

[Is it legal to have children of an anchor tag (<a>) in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289583/is-it-legal-to-have-children-of-an-anchor-tag-a-in-html)