# How to add Javascript onClick Function with Laravel Route

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, onclick, laravel-5.8

I have added a link with Javascript onClick function goes like this:

I also need to add a route of Laravel, so I added this:

```
<div onclick="location.href='{{ route(\'shopping-products.show\', $newest->prd_slug) }}';" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

But this returns this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ''shopping-products.show\', $ne' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) (View: index.blade.php)
```

So how to add Laravel route with onClick function of Javascript, properly?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you just use an `<a/>` tag?

Comment: @Rwd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251704/how-to-make-the-whole-product-item-card-clickable/68251743?noredirect=1#comment120625260_68251743

Comment: Four questions in three hours suggests that you are probably not doing enough research on your problems. Please consider spending more time investigating them. You may find that you can solve some of your own problems if you do that research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of backslash

```
<div onclick="location.href='{{ route('shopping-products.show', $newest->prd_slug) }}';" style="cursor: pointer;">
```